# OpenStack DNS query reply from unexpected source (wrong port)

Tags: dns, dnsmasq, openstack

I had some problem with the DNS queries.
I setted security groups (now every traffic is allowed in theory). The DNS servers are 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4, setted by subnetwork.

When I start a DNS query from openstack instance ( everything is Ubuntu 16.04), a got the following lines:

```
ubuntu@ubi:~$ dig +short google.com
;; reply from unexpected source: 8.8.8.8#12, expected 8.8.8.8#53
;; reply from unexpected source: 8.8.4.4#12, expected 8.8.4.4#53
```

It's not always from the port 12, it' s changing sometimes, but never 53.

Tcpdump On Compute node (everything looks good):

```
admin@aio1:~$ sudo tcpdump -i br-vlan -n -v udp port 53
tcpdump: listening on br-vlan, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
19:54:35.119619 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 116, id 47667, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 83) 
   8.8.8.8.53 > 172.29.249.123.42898: 55409 1/0/1 google.com. A 172.217.18.174 (55)
19:54:36.124083 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 117, id 33490, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 83)
    8.8.4.4.53 > 172.29.249.123.53595: 55409 1/0/1 google.com. A 216.58.205.238 (55)
```

On instance (not really good):

```
root@ubi:~# tcpdump -n -v udp
tcpdump: listening on ens3, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
20:01:15.183943 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 60103, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 67)
    192.168.1.11.55989 > 8.8.8.8.53: 32787+ [1au] A? google.com. (39)
20:01:15.197552 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 115, id 2674, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 83)
    8.8.8.8.12 > 192.168.1.11.55989: UDP, length 55
20:01:16.176863 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 9007, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 67)
    192.168.1.11.40758 > 8.8.4.4.53: 32787+ [1au] A? google.com. (39)
20:01:16.200945 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 117, id 34021, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 83)
    8.8.4.4.12 > 192.168.1.11.40758: UDP, length 55
```

I have tried a lot of things.
My machines:
I'm working on GCP, it's an all-in-on cluster by ansible:

Server: aio1 
CPU: 4 vCPU 
RAM: 26 GB 
IP: 10.1.0.7

Instance: ubi (OpenStack Instance) 
CPU: 1 vCPU 
RAM: 1 GB 
Private ip: 192.168.1.11 (from 192.168.1.0/24 private subnet)
Floating: 172.29.249.123 (from 172.29.248.0/22 public subnet)

Best regards,
Bence